# What type of hose do I need for Propane dryer?

Tags: dryer, propane

I converted my gas dryer over to propane, but I am trying to find out if I can use my older gas line or what type of propane line do I need to buy?

Comment: What line are you referring to?

Comment: The situation isn't clear.  Did you have a utility gas pipe running to your house and then to the dryer (and anything else, like a furnace or stove?).  Then you got a buried propane tank and want to connect it where the utility gas meter previously fed, and use the existing gas line(s) in the house?  Or you moved from a house with utility gas to a house with propane and want to connect your existing gas dryer to the propane line in the house reusing as much of the gas plumbing that previously fed the dryer as possible?  Something else?